# Botão Follow/unFollow em um lsitView populado por uma requisição a um Webservice REST

Tags: android

Então galera, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Eu tenho um `ListView` que é popular por uma requisição ao meu Web service REST. Cada item desta `ListView` possui um botão. Ao clicar neste botão, o usuário logado no aplicativo  será capaz de "seguir" ou "deixar de seguir" a entidade representada no item(algo bem similar ao que acontece quando você "segue" um perfil no Instagram, por exemplo).

A minha duvida é, como manter o status do botão  no `ListView` (se o usuário esta seguindo, escreve "seguindo", se não escreve "seguir"). 
Será que a melhor maneira seria eu já enviar se o usuário segue ou não aquela entidade na própria resposta do *request* ao Web service que preenche a lista, manipulando o JSON retornado?

Aceito sugestões =)

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo problema em já enviar na resposta do webservice o status "seguindo" de cada item (`true` ou `false`, `1` ou `0`, ou como preferir). Você vê algum problema nisso?

Quando o usuário tocar no botão de um item (*"Seguir"* ou *"Deixar de seguir"*), cabe a você decidir como implementar a troca de estado. Por simplicidade você pode fazer um webservice que faz *toggle* de estado, isto é, alterna de um estado para outro sem se importar com o estado inicial. Ele é chamado, verifica no servidor qual é o estado atual e troca esse estado, retornando o novo estado para que você possa atualizar a sua *view*.

Ou então você faz um webservice mais exigente em relação à consistência dos dados: ele recebe o estado atual (`true` ou `false`), valida no servidor se o estado é esse mesmo, troca o estado, e retorna o novo estado, caso contrário retorna erro (*HTTP 400 - Bad Request*, por exemplo).